# 2011 Jetta rear brake drum removal

Tags: brakes, vw, jetta

Can anyone tell me how to remove rear brake drum from a 2011 VW Jetta? I can't tell if it should just pull off or does the center hub nut need to be removed. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

If this is what your rear drum looks like:

[image]

There probably is a Torx head screw in the "6th hole" (smaller hole located at about 2 o'clock in this photo). All you should have to do is remove the Torx screw and ensure the e-brakes are not engaged. If the e-brakes are too tight, you may need to back them off mechanically. You should be able to find an adjustment slot for them in the back of the dust cover. After that, it should come off, though may take a little persuasion to make it happen. The hub which sticks through the center may be rusted somewhat to the brake drum. If so, a little lubrication may help. Then more persuasion. You should not have to take the hub off to service this, even if you can get to the hub.

Comment: Good one, so the Torx is the security bolt, not on the hub itself (this was not clear from the OP's description). I have seen various combinations of one Philips screw, one Torx screw or two Torxs to secure a disc rotor against the axle, but this use on a drum brake is new to me. Live and learn! ;-)

Comment: @ALANWARD - Please understand, a lot of this is an educated guess, especially since there isn't complete information in the question. The image is from the OP's year of Jetta. It doesn't include provisions for a race or hub. The "6th hole" is beveled and since the OP stated a *Tork bolt* [sic] I'm assuming this is the provision for it. Just a lot of putting 2+2 together and coming up with 15 ;-) You never know, I could be wrong ... wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Which is why photo of the offending part by the OP would have been useful indeed. :-D I think you got it, even based on incomplete information. The only doubt left in my mind is why we are still futzing around with drum brakes on what is practically a new car in this day and age, since the handbrake problem with disks has long been solved.

Comment: @ALANWARD - Agreed: drum on new-ish car is strange. Even my '04 Jetta had rear disk brakes. PITB to get the caliper retracted on them, but they were there.

Answer (score 0):

If it is anything like the old VW Golf II I ran way back when -and, judging from the photos on the Internet, it does seem identical to all intents and purposes- you will need to take out the split pin and castellated hub nut in order to remove the drum.

It does seem a quite fiddly job, though, with the various springs and wedges that need to be set correctly.

Comment: It doesn't have a standard hub nut and split pin like the old ones did. This has, what looks like, some sort of spline nut. almost like a massive Tork bolt.

Comment: Is there any way to add a picture to this thread?

Comment: @Mike, sure, just edit the question and there is a button a bit like an outlined painting to click on and add a photo. That would indeed be useful. I am already wondering about the Tork (Torx?).

Comment: A 12 sided multipoint bolt?  Most sockets should still fit on this type of bolt unless you are using a six sided socket.  The modern Polos have these on the front too.